# How to gray out UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I’m working my way through Beginning iPhone Development with Swift. I want to make UITableView 'gray out' while editing in UISearchBar is being active. For instance check out 'f b messenger' iOS application. There are many things we can do for this like., changing alpha value or changing background color to gray, I'm looking for a robust way. Any comments and suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.
[image: Check out the UITableView and UISearchBar on left]

Comment: Just add a subView with background black and alpha 0.6 and then remove it from after finishing search or when its canceled.

Comment: Yep, adding a subView sounds acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need:

```
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
```